# Using angularjs, how do I data bind two objects separately?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to be able to have multiple input fields be able to change an object that is returned from an ajax call. I'm not sure how I can prevent the linking of the two objects.

```
$scope.items = [{value: 1},{value: 2},{value: 3}];
$scope.itemEdit1 = $scope.items;
$scope.itemEdit2 = $scope.items;
```

Do I have to each edit in a different scope?
Here is a fiddle describing my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/htTQc/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Seems like maybe you want to copy the objects, so you're not editing the same reference? Just use `angular.copy`. [Docs here.](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.copy)

```
$scope.items = [{value: 1},{value: 2},{value: 3}];
$scope.itemEdit1 = angular.copy($scope.items);
$scope.itemEdit2 = angular.copy($scope.items);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/blesh/htTQc/1/

Comment: Didn't know angularjs creates shallow copies on assignment. Is this a feature or because of the way angular handles objects in closures?

Comment: This didn't have much to do with Angular; It's because `$scope.items`, `$scope.itemEdit1` and `$scope.itemEdit2` are all the same reference to the same Array. You create one array, then you create two variables that reference the same thing.  `$scope.itemEdit1 === $scope.itemEdit2` will return `true` in the code from your OP.